# How to make a TeamViewer proxy on a Windows 8 machine?

Tags: proxy, teamviewer

I sit on a corporate network which routes all the traffic through a proxy. This proxy routing happens after the computer is connected to the network, because no setup is needed on the computers that connect to the network. I include this in case it makes a difference when it comes to setting up my own proxy server.

The problem is that this proxy server blocks TeamViewer, a program I need. I've talked to the network administrators, but they told me the block is placed on someone even higher than them, so they told me to make a proxy server.

I have a computer at home running Windows 8. How can I set up a proxy server on this computer and connect to it from inside the corporate network to be able to use TeamViewer? I suppose it has to run on port 80 or something like that, so that it doesn't get cut off by the firewall/proxy on the corporate network?

(I'm talking about two proxies here, 1 on the corporate network which all the traffic is routed through, and the one I want to set up on the personal computer at home.)

Comment: You're probably looking at something more like a VPN. It's moderately difficult to set up OpenVPN to listen on TCP port 80 (or 443), which is usually open on outgoing firewalls.

Comment: Okay, so I'll need a VPN network even though I'm not going to connect to any of the computers inside of my home network? Is it because it's easier to get it to work through the corporate proxy?

Comment: A VPN can tunnel anything. A SOCKS proxy may work for TeamViewer, but it also might not. A standard HTTP proxy often does not work. A web proxy will definitely not work. Note that this also depends on the setup that is currently blocking you. If it's a forced webproxy, you're going to have more trouble. If it's simply a firewall blocking most outgoing ports, then it's far easier.

Comment: It's an advanced firewall blocking many things. TeamViewer used to work, but it's selective. It almost seems like it reads all the packets to see what it is before it decides if it should block the packet or not

Comment: @Bob So the proxy will probably work if it's encrypted I think. But it seems like you have a lot of experience with this! Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can a VPN be used instead of a proxy server when configuring TeamViewer?

Comment: Maybe the Solution isn't a Proxy but a simple SSH Tunnel to reroute the TeamViewer Connection over the PC at you're Home. Also if your IT-People say it comes from Someone higher than them maybe you can get in Contact with him/her and let him/her know why you need Teamviewer

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Teamviewer uses your system connection settings by default, I can use it through a port 80/443 http proxy with no troubles.

If you have something more advanced that interrogates your packets, then I'm not sure what you would do. Without knowing more about it, it is difficult to comment.

You could set up a VPN tunnel, OpenVPN will run over a proxy but if your firewall won't allow Teamviewer traffic I don't see why it would allow VPN traffic.

Comment: It is a pretty advanced firewall that selectively blocks services. So I need a proxy through port 80 that encrypts the packets in a way that the firewall doesn't realize it's not regular web packets. (Make it think it's regular internet packets over HTTPS SSL.)